# Window.Margin & Window.Padding don't work

Tags: wpf, xaml, window, padding, margin

I am setting peroperty Margin and Padding of a window and it doesn't take effect:

Here is an example:

```
<Window
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight"
    ResizeMode="NoResize"
    Padding="22"
    Margin="22">

    <Grid>
        <Label 
            FontWeight="Bold"
            FontSize="36"
            BorderThickness="1"
            BorderBrush="Red"
            Content="Hello world!"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Result:
[image]

The desired result is that the red frame of the lable should be away 44px from the window's frame (margin+padding).

Yes, I know I can set the margin of the label, but that's not what I want.
I have a whole project that all its windows are set to a style, I want to set this properties (or other) in the general window style.

I guess if I won't find any solution I will create a named style for greed where I will set the margin/padding, then I will go Window by window and set the Grid's style, but that's the last option I wanna do.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's not surprising that Margin doesn't work, because Margin is the amount of space to be placed *around* the control.  For a Window, this would mean making the frame smaller (and offset), not the client area, and that would be a bit strange (and might not play nicely with the Win32 hosting environment, not sure).  It *is* a bit surprising that Padding doesn't work, and I'm not sure why that would be.

However, there is a workaround which you can encapsulate in a style: replace the default Window ControlTemplate with your own template that does respect the Padding:

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="Window">
  <Border Background="White" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}">
    <ContentPresenter />
  </Border>
</ControlTemplate>
```

(You would probably want the Border Background to be the dynamic window background brush for production code, but you get the idea.)

Obviously you can put this template in a style Template setter so as to avoid having to repeat it on each Window.

Here is the full template (generated with Microsoft Expression):

```
<Style x:Key="WindowStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Window}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Window}">
                <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                    BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                    BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                    Margin="{TemplateBinding Margin}"
                    Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}">

                    <AdornerDecorator>
                        <ContentPresenter/>
                    </AdornerDecorator>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="ResizeMode" Value="CanResizeWithGrip">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Window}">
                        <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                            BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                            BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">

                            <Grid>
                                <AdornerDecorator>
                                    <ContentPresenter/>
                                </AdornerDecorator>
                                <ResizeGrip
                                    x:Name="WindowResizeGrip"
                                    HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                                    VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
                                    IsTabStop="false"
                                    Visibility="Collapsed"
                                />
                            </Grid>
                        </Border>
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <MultiTrigger>
                                <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                    <Condition
                                        Property="ResizeMode"
                                        Value="CanResizeWithGrip"
                                    />
                                    <Condition 
                                        Property="WindowState"
                                        Value="Normal"
                                    />
                                </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                <Setter 
                                    Property="Visibility"
                                    TargetName="WindowResizeGrip"
                                    Value="Visible"/>
                            </MultiTrigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Comment: I tried, and unfortunately it doesn't work. I guess the reason is that when you target window with ControlTemplate.DataType you target only Window base class but not Window1 that inherits from window. Am I wrong?
Besides, I am thinking that it might be dangerous to mess with the Template since it might contain other definitions I will lose.
Whatcha say, should I give up and do Plan B?

Comment: Hmm, I didn't try the default style key approach, but it usually works okay with derived classes (because they inherit the default style key from the base class).  But you can still create the Style as an application-level resource and reference it explicitly via a StaticResource.  Re messing with the Template, hey, that's what templates are for!  \*grin\*  If you're dubious, get the Reflector BAML Viewer add-in and see if there is a default Window template you can adapt (sorry, don't have it installed here so can't check myself).

Answer (score 7):

Here's a simple alternative: just set a background colour on your `Window` and the `Margin` on the `Grid` within your `Window`:

[image]

[image]